# Extract a specific HTML onclick event with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, href, scrape

I'am looking for help from you guys , because I'm having big problem, which I can't solve and find any help on the internet.

I'm having code like this:

```
    <span class="test taLnk hvrIE6" onclick="ta.trackEventOnPage('Hotel_Review'
       ,'URL_HOTEL|text|2||', '74682', 0, false);
                  ; ta.trackEventOnPage('BusinessListings', 'BL_CLICK', 'BL_LINKS');
; ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(14447); ta.call('ta.util.link.targetBlank', event, this,
{'aHref':'LqM40VxEncpMVqnEiaqih1TJctV0iMn17ptSCVttRStISCytxGEc0M1kd3vX0pEc1U',
'isAsdf':true, 'detailId': 74682, 'action': 'website', 'newTab': true })">Hotel website</span>
```

And I want to extract the website link from it and paste it into excel cell.
I'm unfortunately not an expert in excel vba yet, so will appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: It would help to show exactly what the extracted should look like

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crude example you can put into Module 1 then call from the Excel formula.

Change the formatLink to whatever the proper classification is.

```
Function getURL(ByVal s As String)
Dim posStartLink As Integer
Dim posEndLink As Integer
Dim formatLink As String

formatLink = "http://somethingsomething.something/"

posStartLink = InStr(1, s, "'aHref':'") + 9 'get to the start of link
posEndLink = InStr(posStartLink, s, "'")

getURL = formatLink & Mid(s, posStartLink, posEndLink - posStartLink)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
    =getURL(A1)
```

Value:

```
http://somethingsomething.something/LqM40VxEncpMVqnEiaqih1TJctV0iMn17ptSCVttRStISCytxGEc0M1kd3vX0pEc1U
```

Comment: This unfortunatley didn't help. I actually want to get the URL it's throwing out after I click the button on a website